# react-scripts build very slow

Tags: reactjs

It takes more than 25 minutes to run "react-scripts build" in the cloud. On my PC it is somewhat fast (like 2 min). I tried to disable ES lint, and that didn't make any difference. Here's what I have:

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:16-alpine AS ui-build
WORKDIR /usr/src/app 
COPY . .
RUN cd /usr/src/app && npm install --force && npm run build

FROM nginx:alpine
RUN rm -rf /usr/share/nginx/html/*
COPY --from=ui-build /usr/src/app/build/ /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 3000 80

ENTRYPOINT ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "hyper-react",
  "version": "3.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@ag-grid-community/all-modules": "^27.3.0",
    "@ag-grid-community/core": "^28.2.1",
    "@ag-grid-community/react": "^28.2.1",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.2.1",
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^6.2.1",
    "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^6.2.1",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.2.1",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.2.0",
    "@fullcalendar/bootstrap": "^5.10.1",
    "@fullcalendar/core": "^5.10.1",
    "@fullcalendar/daygrid": "^5.10.1",
    "@fullcalendar/interaction": "^5.10.1",
    "@fullcalendar/list": "^5.10.1",
    "@fullcalendar/react": "^5.10.1",
    "@fullcalendar/timegrid": "^5.10.1",
    "@hookform/resolvers": "^2.8.8",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.2",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.3",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "apexcharts": "^3.33.1",
    "axios": "^0.26.0",
    "axios-mock-adapter": "^1.20.0",
    "bootstrap": "5.1.3",
    "britecharts-react": "^0.6.5",
    "chart.js": "3.7.1",
    "classnames": "^2.3.1",
    "draft-js": "^0.11.7",
    "draftjs-to-html": "^0.9.1",
    "easymde": "^2.16.1",
    "env-cmd": "^10.1.0",
    "frappe-gantt": "^0.6.0",
    "google-maps-react": "^2.0.6",
    "i18next": "^21.6.12",
    "i18next-browser-languagedetector": "^6.1.3",
    "jsvectormap": "1.3.1",
    "jwt-decode": "^3.1.2",
    "nouislider-react": "^3.4.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.8.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-albus": "^2.0.0",
    "react-apexcharts": "^1.3.9",
    "react-beautiful-dnd": "^13.1.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.1.2",
    "react-bootstrap-typeahead": "^6.0.0-alpha.9",
    "react-chartjs-2": "4.0.1",
    "react-datepicker": "^4.7.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-draft-wysiwyg": "^1.14.7",
    "react-dropzone": "^12.0.4",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.27.1",
    "react-i18next": "^11.15.5",
    "react-rating": "^2.0.5",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.6",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.2.2",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "react-select": "^5.2.2",
    "react-simplemde-editor": "^5.0.2",
    "react-table": "^7.7.0",
    "react-text-mask": "^5.4.3",
    "redux": "^4.1.2",
    "redux-saga": "^1.1.3",
    "sass": "^1.49.9",
    "simplebar-react": "^2.3.6",
    "universal-cookie": "^4.0.4",
    "uuidv4": "^6.2.13",
    "web-vitals": "^1.0.1",
    "yup": "^0.32.9"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "env-cmd -f .env.development react-scripts start",
    "build": "DISABLE_ESLINT_PLUGIN=true react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "flow": "flow",
    "format": "prettier --write 'src/**/*.js'"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "flow-bin": "^0.153.0",
    "prettier": "2.3.1",
    "redux-saga-test-plan": "^4.0.1"
  }
}
```

On gcloud, the build lingers on this command for 99% of the build time:

> Step #0 - "Build docker image": > hyper-react@3.0.0 build Step #0 -
> "Build docker image": > DISABLE_ESLINT_PLUGIN=true react-scripts build
> Step #0 - "Build docker image":  Step #0 - "Build docker image":
> (node:105) [DEP0148] DeprecationWarning: Use of deprecated folder
> mapping "./" in the "exports" field module resolution of the package
> at
> /usr/src/app/node_modules/postcss-safe-parser/node_modules/postcss/package.json.
> Step #0 - "Build docker image": Update this package.json to use a
> subpath pattern like "./*". Step #0 - "Build docker image": (Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created) Step #0 - "Build docker image": Creating an optimized production build... Step #0 - "Build docker image": Browserslist: caniuse-lite is
> outdated. Please run: Step #0 - "Build docker image": npx
> browserslist@latest --update-db Step #0 - "Build docker image":  Step
> #0 - "Build docker image": Why you should do it regularly: Step #0 - "Build docker image":
> https://github.com/browserslist/browserslist#browsers-data-updating